# Using Google Gson in ADF Mobile Application

Tags: gson, oracle-adf-mobile

Trying to use Gson in ADF Mobile project,

Downloaded the Jar files from Google https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Created A library in JDEV (Tools => Manage Libraries )

Added it to the ViewController project in my application ( Project Properties => Libraries and Classpath)

So now the library appears in (Application Resources => Libraries )

Added it to the Application Deployment Profile

Creates the below simple method to test

```
    public void AlertCart2(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

         Gson gson = new Gson();

    }
```

Created a button to invoke that method (but i get Invocation error)

Did i miss any thing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without specifying the error you get it is hard to know where the problem is.
But my guess would be that the library doesn't work with the JDK 1.4 used by ADF Mobile.

Comment: True, thank you Shay, i won't work with JDK 1.4, at lease 1.5 is required

Answer (score 0):

Dont start method with uppercase and paste stacktrace.

Comment: thanks for the advice, it was for testing so i wrote it on a hurry, but i won't again, promise :)